# Solaris 10 vs Solaris 9 Executable Compatibility

Tags: c++, oracle

I've compiled my exe on Solaris 10. However i have another server running Solaris 9. When I run the exe on Solaris 9, it's giving me and error.

**ld.so.1: bgProcess: fatal: libm.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
Killed**

What do I need to do to make the the exe compatible on Solaris 9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing `libm.so.2`, I would look into getting that first.

Comment: will copying the files from Solaris 10 to 9 work?

Comment: copying should work. In the worst case, compile on Solaris 9, and copy the executable forward.